# scons is not building when using -j option

Tags: scons

I really am not sure how to describe this issue.
Building with *scons -uj4* or *scons -u -j4* had always worked, but recently it just stopped working!

running  *scons -uj4* or *scons -u -j4* will return;

```
scons: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/somedir'
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
```

running scons -u will display;

```
scons: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/somedir'
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: target
```

I've spent so much time trying to figure it out, with no success.

Thanks in advance for you help :)

[EDIT]

Added more required info;

```
scons: script: v2.4.0.rel_2.4.0:3365:9259ea1c13d7, 2015/09/21 14:03:43, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
babun version 1.2.0
uname -a -> CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW 2.7.0(0.306/5/3) 2017-02-12 13:13 i686 Cygwin
python --version: Python 2.7.12
```

Some Sconscript optimisation...

```
....
AddOption('--optimise', dest='optimised', default=False, action='store_true', help='Optimise Win32 Build')
....
env.SetOption('implicit_cache', 1)
env.SetOption('max_drift', 5)
env.Decider('MD5-timestamp')
```

I Added some breakpoints in scons-2.4.0\SCons\Script\Main.py and found out that scons is crashing here: Job.py(365)**init**()

```
self.tp = ThreadPool(num, stack_size, self.interrupted)
```

Comment: More info please.  Platform? Version of Python? Version of SCons? Example SConstruct which demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this issue (not being able to parallel build with -j option) has nothing to do with Scons, it was caused by the company's antivirus, **Trend Micro**.

For some reason, Trend Micro does not allow cygwin's python to create any sub-processes! Currently, since Trend Micro is company policy (not allowed to uninstall) the work around is to use uninstall cygwin python and use Windows Python (or Anaconda). Others opted to use a Virtual Machine...

Thank you all.